# Which is best method to send and receive data between Android and MongoDB?

Tags: json, web-services, mongodb

I want to know  , which is best method to send and receive data between android and mongodb server  ?

And what kind web service is good to work with mongodb , I know that python works with mongodb pretty good than php ..

Comment: Mongo has some [http interfaces](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface) you might be interested in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best method is to have some kind of server in front of mongodb. you might not want to expose your db to the world directly.

between android and server you can choose whatever protocol you want. between server and mongodb, you use the appropriate driver.

But if you insist on communicating with mongodb directly from android, the latest java driver should work, according to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-295

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON over HTTP. Since mongo supports JSON for its document store, it is quite natural.